# laravel insert stopped working Incorrect datetime value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I can't insert  or update anything

I get this error

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '2018-03-25 02:00:06' for column 'updated_at' at row

The date is inserted automatically by laravel  how can I  solve this issue

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

it was database issue

I used timestamp type for the column and the was the issue

once I changed all columns date types to datetime it worked  normally.

Comment: I know this is very old, but it looks like the timestamp is correct and this was a daylight savings error. If anyone else finds this answer, see here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55084109/6038111

Answer (score 0):

you should change database config file according this:

```
//config/database.php
'mysql' => [
    'strict' => false,
]
```