# Laravel SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-10 02:00:39' for column 'updated_at' (daylight savings?)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel application with a queue worker, and it just started failing and throwing a constant stream of exceptions to the log. Here is one of them:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-10 02:00:39' for column 'updated_at' at row 1 (SQL: update `videos` set `updated_at` = 2019-03-10 02:00:39 where `id` = 30860)
```

A few things to note:

- The timestamp *appears* to be the correct format
- The column is a MySQL TIMESTAMP type (nullable), using InnoDB
- The `updated_at` field is managed by Laravel defaults, with nothing custom happening for the date formatting
- I'm not using any date mutators, or anything that would be changing the value before save
- This code has been running for weeks without any issue
- No code has changed recently
- I did a `git checkout .` and `composer install` to make sure none of the library files had changed or been corrupted somehow (no change)
- **The error first appeared at `2019-03-10 02:00:39` (UTC), which is 8pm local (Central) time**

> Daylight saving time 2019 in Minnesota will begin at 2:00 AM on
> Sunday, March 10
>
> -- Google

Everything I can find on google is related to somebody using a blatantly wrong time format, so that hasn't helped me figure it out.

I feel like there is too much of a coincidence between the errors starting at 02:00 *UTC* on the same day when daylight savings is supposed to begin at 02:00 *US Central Time*, but I don't have a clue why it would be throwing this error when timestamps are managed by the framework and converted to UTC before saving (and UTC doesn't change for daylight savings).

MySQL 5.5.45
Laravel 5.7.28
nesbot/carbon 1.36.2
PHP 7.2.7

config/database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

What could be causing the date value to be recognized as invalid?

**Edit:** I've determined this is definitely a daylight savings error, as clocks skip forward 1 hour and times between 02:00 and 03:00 are invalid in US Central Time. What I don't understand is why a TIMESTAMP field on an application set to UTC would be throwing an error? How can UTC be affected by daylight savings, and what can I do to prevent this when the timestamp is managed by the framework (Laravel+Carbon)?

Comment: You should have edited your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083933/mysql-weird-date-error-incorrect-datetime-value?noredirect=1#comment96913607_55083933) rather than posting a new one.  Do you have more than one username on this site?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for taking the time to reply! However, I did not post that question.

Comment: Also, your error message appears to be coming from SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's an `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` from Laravel, and I can assure you it's MySQL 5.5.45 as stated in the question. I thought including the full stack trace wouldn't be much help since the exception was thrown by the database error that I've shown.

Comment: It's going to be really "fun" if MySQL has some kind of crippling DST bug that's just showing up now.

Comment: Travis, I have a hunch here.  I think what is happening is that your March 1 date is being adjusted backwards to Feb _29_, or something like this.  But, I don't have a fix.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was due to my MySQL server's `time_zone` setting being set to `SYSTEM` (and my system is US Central). Laravel is providing timestamps that were already converted to UTC, but my database is interpreting them as US Central due to the `time_zone` setting. The times are actually being converted *again* internally by MySQL to a "real" UTC unix timestamp representation (which will be incorrect because it's offset by the time zone), even though they appear to be UTC already in every query because they also get converted back to US Central again for reading (I know right).

Because of this, at 20:00:39 (8:00 PM) local time my Laravel UTC timestamps are 02:00:39. MySQL interprets these times as US Central time, and because the time is between 02:00 and 03:00 (which is when clocks skip forward for US Central), the time is invalid.

The best solution for a Laravel application is to force every database connection to use a `+00:00` timezone (or whatever you have set as the application timezone in `config/app.php`) so there will not be a secondary conversion happening. This can be done in `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql' => [
    // ...

    'timezone'  => '+00:00'
],
```

This way you are not at the mercy of your database server if it has a configured timezone that is different from your Laravel application. The other option is to change the database's `time_zone` setting, but then you still risk the bug recurring if you ever change hosts or need to rebuild the server for any reason (and don't configure the timezone correctly again), or affecting other databases on the server.

Important note: Since all of the previous timestamps were being offset internally by MySQL from the configured time zone to UTC unix timestamps (which, again, were wrong because the records were already UTC) it might be necessary to run a data migration to correct the old timestamps. I haven't investigated further because for my application it doesn't matter if the old timestamps were wrong by a few hours.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times!

Comment: Ha. I had the same problem but by the time I had worked out the issue the hour had passed and I had a whole year to fix it. Until predictably a year later the same thing reoccurred. To be honest, this seems like a bug as the second conversion should not be happening. But you're solution works great. I've also set my server clock to UTC and then restarted MySQL.

Comment: @Gazzer did those changes actually fix your old timestamps? The "real" unix timestamps MySQL was saving would have been offset by the difference between your app timezone and your database timezone. I thought fixing that would require a data migration to correct the offset, but I never bothered to check because in my app I just didn't care if the old records were wrong by 6 hours.

Comment: Wow, thanks you so much. This solved my problem!

Comment: @TravisBritz My understanding is that there is nothing to be fixed (but I could be wrong). What is stored is still the UTC time and that won't change. The only thing that changes is when you run a select is that what the client outputs is the local time. In other words, the internal saved data is not changed. This can be confusing because when you run a `SELECT` what you see is the converted time giving the impression this is what is inside the database. This is why I think this is a bug.

Comment: @Gazzer my understanding is that for `TIMESTAMP` types, MySQL will convert them from the connection timezone to UTC and then save them internally  as a unix timestamp. Since the *values* Laravel provided were UTC but the *connection* was  not, the internal timestamps that MySQL thinks are now UTC are in fact wrong. If you read back the values in the same timezone they were set in, everything will look fine, but if you suddenly change the connection timezone then the conversions MySQL does for you will end up with the wrong values. If correctness is important for your app, I'd triple check.

Comment: @TravisBritz Luckily, these times are not important to me. I fully expect this post will get a new lease of life in March 2022 :-)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me: `'strict' => false,` in `config.datebase.mysql`