# Why does this insert error occur in the Laravel project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using a SQL INSERT in Laravel.

SQL returns an error when I use the Laravel query builder.

But SQL INSERT directly on the server normally succeeds.

[image]
[image]

```
$results = DB::table('tbl_corona_region')->insert(
                [
                 'seq' => "{$data->item[$i]->seq}",
                 'create_dt' => "'{$createDt}'",
                 'region_nm' => "'{$data->item[$i]->gubun}'",
                 'region_cn' => "'{$data->item[$i]->gubunCn}'",
                 'region_en' => "'{$data->item[$i]->gubunEn}'",
                 'defCnt' => "{$data->item[$i]->defCnt}",
                 'incDec' => "{$data->item[$i]->incDec}",
                 'deathCnt' => "{$data->item[$i]->deathCnt}",
                 'isolIngCnt' => "{$data->item[$i]->isolIngCnt}",
                 'isolClearCnt' => "{$data->item[$i]->isolClearCnt}",
                 'localOccCnt' => "{$data->item[$i]->localOccCnt}",
                 'overFlowCnt' => "{$data->item[$i]->overFlowCnt}",
                 //'qurRate' => "{$data->item[$i]->qurRate}",
                 'stdDay' => "'2021-07-10 00:00:00'",
                 'update_dt' => "'2021-07-10 00:00:00'"
                ]                              
            );
```

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
> value: ''2021-07-09 09:43:18'' for column 'create_dt' at row 1 (SQL:
> insert into `tbl_corona_region` (`seq`, `create_dt`, `region_nm`,
> `region_cn`, `region_en`, `defCnt`, `incDec`, `deathCnt`,
> `isolIngCnt`, `isolClearCnt`, `localOccCnt`, `overFlowCnt`, `stdDay`,
> `update_dt`) values (10628, '2021-07-09 09:43:18', '검역', '隔離區',
> 'Lazaretto', 4492, 39, 5, 383, 4104, 0, 39, '2021-07-10 00:00:00',
> '2021-07-10 00:00:00'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove quotes

```
$results = DB::table('tbl_corona_region')->insert(
            [
                'seq' => $data->item[$i]->seq,
                'create_dt' => $createDt,
                'region_nm' => $data->item[$i]->gubun,
                'region_cn' => $data->item[$i]->gubunCn,
                'region_en' => $data->item[$i]->gubunEn,
                'defCnt' => $data->item[$i]->defCnt,
                'incDec' => $data->item[$i]->incDec,
                'deathCnt' => $data->item[$i]->deathCnt,
                'isolIngCnt' => $data->item[$i]->isolIngCnt,
                'isolClearCnt' =>$data->item[$i]->isolClearCnt,
                'localOccCnt' => $data->item[$i]->localOccCnt,
                'overFlowCnt' =>$data->item[$i]->overFlowCnt,
                //'qurRate' => "{$data->item[$i]->qurRate",
                'stdDay' => "2021-07-10 00:00:00",
                'update_dt' => "2021-07-10 00:00:00"
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your time zone, see the below question with the same problem:

[Laravel SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-10 02:00:39' for column 'updated_at' (daylight savings?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084109/laravel-sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value)